# Why does the proof of the disjointedness of equivalence classes not account for when an equivalence class is just a subset of another?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

I saw a proof of the disjointedness of two equivalence classes. The proof was as follows:

Suppose we have two equivalence classes $[a]\not=[b]$. We'll show they are disjoint. Suppose $x\in[a]\cap[b]$. Then, $x\sim a$ and $x\sim b$. By symmetry, $a\sim x$, and hence, by transitivity, $a\sim b$. Therefore, $[a]=[b]$, which is a contradiction.

My problem with this proof is that it is possible that the two equivalence classes are unequal but one is a subset of the other. For example, under the following relation: $a \sim b$ iff $a \equiv b$ (mod 3), $A = [2] \cup [3]$ is an equivalence class, $[2] \neq A$ but $[2] \cap A \neq \emptyset $ and therefore $A$ and $[2]$ are not disjoint. We have two non-disjoint equivalence classes that are unequal. Is something wrong with the proof? If yes, how do I fix the proof above? If not, why does my example not apply? And if nothing needs fixing, what am I missing?

For context, the definition of equivalence classes I have in the instructional material is $\forall x \in A$, if $ x \sim y$, $ y \in A$. The proof I found was not in the instructional material; it was said to be trivial to prove. However, for the reason I highlighted above, I could not find a good proof. I considered refining the definition by using the term distinct equivalence classes, but there would be nothing to prove. Even then, I feel like there is a 'localisation behaviour' with equivalence classes I wish to express but cannot. How can I refine the intuition of disjointedness with equivalence classes?

Comment: The $A$ you suggest is *not* an equivalence class with respect to the equivalence relation you have defined.

Comment: I fail to see why that's the case. By the definition I used, $A$ seems to be an equivalence class with respect to the relation. Is there any other definition for equivalence classes where that is not true? Perhaps I miswrote the definition. Here's what it said: Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$, a subset $A$ of $X$ is called an equivalence class if and only if there is an element $x \in A$ such that $A$ consists precisely of those elements y such that $x \sim y$. How does that differ from what I wrote down, if it does at all?

Comment: Both $2$ and $3$ are in the set $A$ that you defined. but "$2 \equiv 3$ mod 3" is not true.. What value of $x$ do you propose that is equivalent to both 2 and 3?

Comment: Ah. Thank you. That was a ridiculous oversight of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@XanderHenderson's comment about your counter-example ($[2] \cup [3]$ is not an equivalence class) is key, but I will say that the proof, as you presented it, seems to finish a little early.

"Two equivalent elements have the same equivalence class" is true, but a proof should be provided (even though the proof is *extremely* short). But most texts make a few remarks about equivalence classes when they introduce them, and they will often demonstrate that fact as part of the remarks.

Also, if you're making your proof more rigorous, you shouldn't be implying, like you do in your title, that  "equivalence classes are disjoint". You should say "equivalence classes either coincide or are disjoint". Then your proof can take two non-disjoint equivalence classes and prove that they are identical. It's basically what you've already written, but I think it's clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can deduce the proof. Given $a \sim b$ $\forall c \in [a]$, $c \sim a$. By transitivity, $c \sim b$, and therefore, $c \in [b]$ and a similar proof will show that $[b] \subset [a]$. As for my question, I made the mistake of not realising that if $a \nsim b$, b is not in *any* equivalence class containing a. It was not in my definition if you noticed. But the definition in the text, states this exactly. It states $A = \{y: x \sim y$ if $x \in A\}$ is an equivalence class. For your advice on rigour, I will put that to heart.

Comment: Great! Believing in an incorrect idea, working hard to prove it, and then unwinding that and seeing where one went wrong is great practice for doing math. Maybe we wish we hadn't done it in public ;-), but it's part of getting mathematical maturity.

Comment: "Maybe we wish we hadn't done it in public" Boy, how true this is. 